# JQuery - Unexpected Token Can't Resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an unexpected token error that I cannot seem to resolve.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="redditSearch"]').on('change', function () {
        var $clone = $(".redditContainer").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#redditMain");
        $clone.attr('id',$clone.attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, function(str) { return parseInt(str) + 1; }) );
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
            var $th = $(this);
            var newID = $th.attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, function(str) { return parseInt(str) + 1; });
            $th.attr('id', newID);

        })

    } //Error appears to be here
        loadRedditData($(this).val());
    });
});
```

The function works if I remove the $clone function inside of it.

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="redditSearch"]').on('change', function () {
        var $clone = $(".redditContainer").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#redditMain");
        $clone.attr('id',$clone.attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, function(str) { return parseInt(str) + 1; }) );
    }
        loadRedditData($(this).val());
    });
});
```

I have tried a few variations of this function but I cannot seem to get it to run without the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close the call to `.each()`

Comment: Hi @David thanks! I did try and fix it by changing to " )} " but for some reason it then says I have an unexpected token further down the line, let me update my code quickly.

Comment: Now you're missing a semi-colon, and you didn't close `.on()` correctly.  Don't just randomly add/remove tokens.  Identify your actual statements and make sure each one is complete and correct.

Comment: You may want to try using [JS Hint](http://jshint.com), or [JS Lint](http://jslint.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add an `')'` and remove `'}'` in the next line

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="redditSearch"]').on('change', function () {
        var $clone = $(".redditContainer").eq(0).clone().appendTo("#redditMain");
        $clone.attr('id',$clone.attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, function(str) { return parseInt(str) + 1; }) );
        $clone.find('[id]').each(function() {
            var $th = $(this);
            var newID = $th.attr('id').replace(/\d+$/, function(str) { return parseInt(str) + 1; });
            $th.attr('id', newID);

        }) //add ) here

        loadRedditData($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe I see the issue now, thanks for both of your help. Sorry for the low-level Jquery question!

Comment: remove "}" in the next line

Comment: That did it. Sorry again for the low level question. I am working on implementing a debugger to help me with things like this in the future.